# How to upload file from MFC client (CInternetSession) to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the MVC app as a service, so i have deleted the views. I am able to make calls to the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Home/
    public string Index(string param1, string param2) {
       ...
    }
```

from the MFC app:

```
string URL(_T("http://localhost:2374/home/index/myparam1/myparam2"));
pHttpFile = dynamic_cast<CHttpFile*> (m_Session.OpenURL(URL));
if (pHttpFile) {
    CHAR szBuff[1024] = { 0 };
    while (pHttpFile->Read(szBuff, 1024) > 0) {
        info += szBuff;
        ...
```

Now to upload an XML file, i am trying this on the MFC client:

```
CHttpConnection *pHttpConn = m_Session.GetHttpConnection(_T("localhost:2374"));
if (pHttpConn)
{
    CHttpFile *pHttpFile = pHttpConn->OpenRequest(
        CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST,
        _T("file.xml"));
    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    pHttpFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);
    if (dwRet == HTTP_STATUS_OK)
    {
        CString headers(_T("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
        if (pHttpFile->AddRequestHeaders(headers))
        {
            if (pHttpFile->SendRequestEx(xml.GetLength(), HSR_SYNC | HSR_INITIATE))
            {
                pHttpFile->Write(xml, xml.GetLength());
                pHttpFile->EndRequest(HSR_SYNC);
                ...
```

and this on the MVC side:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
```

The client executes without error, but nothing happens on server side. I am not sure how to get FileUpload() called in the Controller. Do i use MapRoute(), if so how?

Comment: What is MFC Tell me about them.

Comment: @4thpage: MFC - Microsoft Foundation Classes (VC++).

Comment: Yes, the URL and verb need to match a route that ultimately ends in the `FileUpload()` method. Usually, this would be a POST to `/controllername/FileUpload`. The URL `/home/index/myparam1/myparam2` would usually map to the `Index()` method of the `HomeController` with `myparam1` and `myparam2` as method arguments. The process of mapping an URL to a method in ASP.NET is called *URL Routing* and exists in both ASP.NET 4 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC. How did you come up with ASP.NET MVC as the choice for a service to an MFC client anyway? :)

Comment: @bzlm: The client is in VC++ and cannot use .Net. The server application is a new one and we may host it on Azure. So we chose VS2010 (and hence MVC) as it has good support for Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change nessecary on your server side.

The problem is the c++ client. The url you should call to upload the file is *http://localhost:2374/home/fileupload*. If the method fileupload is in the home controller. You don't need any other route for it.

I found a code sample for upload a file with winnet at code project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/lyoulhttpclient.aspx. I'm not a c++ guy, may be there are more. But this one looks good.

Comment: Yes, the problem indeed is in the client. Changing the 2nd parameter of OpenRequest() fixed the problem:
CHttpFile *pHttpFile = pHttpConn->OpenRequest( 
    CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, 
    _T("home/FileUpload"));
Now Controller's FileUpload() gets called on SendRequest().

Thanks to @Christian13467 and @bzlm.